# Sourcetree on OSX looking for "credential-oskeychain" rather than "credential-osxkeychain"

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

When using Sourcetree, I keep getting the error

```
git: 'credential-oskeychain' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

I'm pretty sure Sourcetree / git should be using

```
credential-osxkeychain"
```

(notice the X in osx, it was missing in the original error)

How do I change this? How in the world did I manage to setup Sourcetree / Git to have this mistyped command? I can't seem to find where to change this

I've run

```
locate credential-oskeychain
```

and not surprisingly, found nothing.

```
locate credential-osxkeychain
```

returns

```
/opt/local/bin/git-credential-osxkeychain
```

among a few others

Thanks in advance for helping a newbie to use Sourcetree

Comment: What version of SourceTree are you using, and are you using embedded or system git?

Comment: Looks like a bug, you should report it to Atlassian

Answer (score 1):

Your helper credential is misspelled.  Your ~/.gitconfig file should have the following entry:

```
[credential]
    helper = osxkeychain
```

but probably has this instead:

```
[credential]
    helper = oskeychain
```